# how to show the media dynamically according to the content(video/audio/picture) sent from Android app to receiver in chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

In chromecast
i want to send different kinds of url(mp4/mp3/png..) to the receiver,but how does the receiver to show them dynamically?
this is: how does the receiver recogonize what kind of the RemoteMedia received?

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of the SDK, there is nothing from the framework side to help you with that directly. You can include the mimetype in the metadata and retrieve that on your receiver and do as you see fit. That said, if your media is only audio or video, things are better since the video element can handle both and you can just treat them the same but for images, you have to do some other work. Another approach is to look at the extension and try to guess the type but that is not fully reliable.